# Snapping to grid in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, grid, snap-to-grid

I'm looking for a javascript function that calculates a snap to grid value using a uniformly spaced grid.

Now I have the following code, which works fine as a basic solution, but now I need it to snap only when within say 2px of the snap position e.g. using a 30px spaced grid and a 2px limit, it would snap between 0px and 2px, 28px and 32px, 58px and 62px, etc.

```
snapToGrip = function(val,gridSize){
    return gridSize * Math.round(val/gridSize);
};
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you consider using jquery UI? [The draggable utility](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#snap-to) allows snapping.

If you really need to implement it, this returns null when
you shouldn't snap.

```
snapToGrip = function(val,gridSize){
    var snap_candidate = gridSize * Math.floor(val/gridSize);
    if (val-snap_candidate < 2) {
        return snap_candidate;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
};
```

To snap on both side :

```
snapToGrip = function(val,gridSize){
    var snap_candidate = gridSize * Math.round(val/gridSize);
    if (Math.abs(val-snap_candidate) < 2) {
        return snap_candidate;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, I considered it, but I'm building a bespoke application that doesn't justify using such a library.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it. I've implemented the code, which works fine when moving an object from right to left (snap point) but not when dragging from left to right (snap point).

Comment: @Steve I don't understand... You said you wanted to snap between 0px and 2px. So you want to do so between -2px and 2px?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Nothing can be dragged beyond the grid - objects are constrained so that they can't be dropped at anything less than 0px.

Comment: you're a star! The solution you provided works like a treat. Thanks a million poulejapon :)

Comment: @Steve oh right, sorry I'm the one who didn't read that properly

Comment: Thanks @poulejapon, I have looked all over and your second snap to grid code snippet is the simplest and best solution.